# How to publish two asp.net mvc 4 applications with same controller names as single site on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 asp.net mvc 4 applications:

- **MVCForum.site** - opensource app with forum and
- **My.Site** - site of my customer

Each of the applications has HomeController.
I need to deploy them to local IIS 7.5 like this:

**my.Site** ->   localhost:81
   I can get to it by URL  `localhost:81/home` or  `localhost:81/`

**MVCForumSite.Site** ->   `localhost:81/forum`
   I can get to it by URL  `localhost:81/forum`

They work separettly, but routing conflict accuries when they start to work at the same time.
*If I use default configuration from customer with Azure emulater, so they work together, but I don't want to use the emulator, because each restart is too long for development.

MVCForum has next routes (bad if need to fix them):

> routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>               routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
>
> ```
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "categoryUrls", // Route name
>             string.Concat(AppConstants.CategoryUrlIdentifier, "/{slug}"), // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Category", action = "Show", slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
>
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "categoryRssUrls", // Route name
>             string.Concat(AppConstants.CategoryUrlIdentifier, "/rss/{slug}"), // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Category", action = "CategoryRss", slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
>
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "topicUrls", // Route name
>             string.Concat(AppConstants.TopicUrlIdentifier, "/{slug}"), // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Topic", action = "Show", slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
>
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "memberUrls", // Route name
>             string.Concat(AppConstants.MemberUrlIdentifier, "/{slug}"), // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Members", action = "GetByName", slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
>
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "tagUrls", // Route name
>             string.Concat(AppConstants.TagsUrlIdentifier, "/{tag}"), // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Topic", action = "TopicsByTag", tag = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
>
>         routes.MapRouteLowercase(
>             "Default", // Route name
>             "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
>             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
>         );
> ```

and My.Site 's RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Could you please help me to deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the next thing has helped:

1. created a site in IIS called **site.localhost**.
2. Created an application inside that **site.localhost->forum** (like internal application)
3. Created a second fake site (for correct moving files while deployement) called **fakeforum.localhost**
4. **site.localhost** looks to  `C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\site`
5. forum (**site.localhost->forum**) looks to  `C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\forum` 
   5  fake forum fakeforum.localhost looks also to  `C:\inetpub\MyWebsite\forum` this helps not  to overwrite configs of **site.localhost** during the publishing of forum.
6. stop **fakeforum.localhost** in IIS and never run it
7. publish mvc app to **site.localhost** in Visual Studio using start url: `localhost:81` and server name `localhost`, site name `site.localhost` (from IIS)
8. publish mvc forum  app to **fakeforum.localhost** using start url: `localhost:81/forum`
   server name `localhost`, site name `fakeforum.localhost` (from IIS)

What it does?

1. It helps to publish - to move files from dev folder to intepub and let xdt:Transform work and don't change you original web.config inside folder for development.
2. It uses IIS in is a cantainer for publishing without running.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't mean that Owen's solution like: routes.IgnoreRoute("Forum/{*pathInfo}"); doesn't work, but my solution works for any routing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in an IgnoreRoute to your My.Site's RouteConfig.cs?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Forum/{*pathInfo}");
```